# Can we call a PHP method through APEX scheduler Batch class?

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch

I have a requirement where i have to call a method written in PHP and is present on an external server? Is it possible to call that method and schedule it to run everyday at some time?

Answer (score 0):

This is a three step high level process:-

1. Create [WSDL](https://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl) class from PHP server, where the method exists.
2. Consume that [WSDL in Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_wsdl_to_package.htm&language=en&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.in%2F&type=0), from where the method needs to be called.
3. Create a [schedulable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm) class in Salesforce and schedule it for the frequency you want to run that method.